# Remove images from wordpress rss feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

How can i modify a standard wordpress feed too remove images?
I cant find any way to do this.

I was thinking of a way just using a function in function.php and remove the img elements with regex

Comment: Better than regex, remove them with an XML parser as feeds are XML. If you add some of the feeds sourcecode, it would be more easy to answer.

Comment: @hakre I don't have any source code more that what twenty-eleven has. And I don't have any template files for rss feeds in my theme folder

Comment: The XML source of the feed, not the wordpress source code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to [create a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) for this and hook on to one of the many [filter hooks WordPress provides](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters), specifically [the_content_feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content_feed).